# Electric Polarisation in Insulators

Tags: electrostatics

If there was a test charge brought near an insulator, it will get polarised. If so, won't there be an electric field inside that insulator (a weak one)?

Comment: Yes. It's there some specific reason why you find that bad or counter-intuitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pretty much all real world insulators are a [dielectrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric). For example silicon dioxide is a good insulator and a good dielectric. Note that there are two fields in the insulator, the field of your test charge and the field created by the charges that are displaced/created by the polarization, and they counteract each other. If it is a good dielectric with a high dielectric constant (i.e. a material that is used as a dielectric in capacitors, for instance), then the field due to polarization is actually not weak, and it almost cancels out the external field of your test charge.